# Conditions with PHP

Tags: php

I'm still pretty new to PHP and trying to figure out an issue I've found on our website at work. In the screenshot, the last `div.image-group` should be inside the `div.image-row` that only has two items in it — basically, I always want the `div.image-group` to be inside a `div.image-row`, which should hold at most three `div.image-group`'s (but the first `div.image-row` might contain fewer).

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction to correct this?

Here's the code:

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
        <?php $counter++; ?>
        <?php if ($counter % 3 == 1 || $counter === 1) { ?>
            <div class="image-row small clearfix">
        <?php } ?>
                <div class="image-group"><?php print $row; ?></div>
        <?php if (($counter != 1 && $counter % 2 == 1) || ($id == count($rows) -1 && $counter % 2 != 1)) { ?>   
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: There's no need to  put `<?php ... ?>` on every line. Use them only when you're switching between PHP and HTML.

Comment: Good to know - thanks @Barmar!

Comment: Rather than the organized DOM from the browser's inspector (or in addition to), can you post the actual HTML source as sent to the browser using your "view source" option?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski In this case I think the image is actually more useful, we can see the grouping, which is the issue.

Comment: Why is it using `$counter % 2` instead of `$counter % 3` in the second `if`?

Comment: FYI, in `if ($counter % 3 == 1 || $counter === 1)`, `$counter === 1` is redundant, since `1 % 3 == 1`.

Comment: hard to tell what you are actually asking about `<?php if ($counter % 3 == 1 || $counter === 1) { ?>` <-- for example has no sense, as if `$counter === 1`, `$counter % 3` will be `1` as well, so it's like the same condition twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will be simpler if you divide the original array into groups of three at the beginning.

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($rows, 3) as $image_row): ?>
    <div class="image-row small clearfix">
        <?php foreach ($image_row as $image_group): ?>
            <div class="image-group"><?= $image_group ?></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I was just going to say, if you don't use 2 loops then on Odd  (not groups of 3) you will probably miss the end tag.  But you beat me to it.  [For Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5943dc3c5e93646c901f8c5c615d32c895842cda)

Comment: Thank you both so much — this is so much cleaner and the logic is much more clear to me!

Answer (score 1):

The second condition should be:

```
    <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0 || $counter == count($rows)) { ?>
```

`$counter % 3 == 0` is true after every third row, and `$counter == count($rows)` is true after the last row.